# UPSIZING ACCESS 2010 to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server-2014, ms-access-2010, ssma

When I run the upsizing module it goes through the motions but the report at the end says

> "table was skipped or export failed"

for each of the tables.

I can't find a solution for this.

I can't figure out why this is?

Comment: Have you tried with the SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54255?

Comment: I'm trying to link access to SQL server. Yes, I tried and copied tables to SQL server.

Comment: I'm going out on a limb and guessing that either the table names are not valid, or there's a column in each table that SQL Server cannot convert.